# Symfony3 render CSS file from Controller

Tags: php, css, symfony-3.2

I would like to do this in Symfony 3 :

```
    public function styleAction()
{
    // Fetch it from service or whatever strategy you have
    $backgroundColor = '#ff0000';

    return $this->render(
        'AcmeMyBundle::somefile.css.twig',
        ['backgroundColor' => $backgroundColor],
        ['Content-Type' => 'text/css']
    );
}
```

But infortunately I still get a problem with the third argument of the render method.

Here is my error message :

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 3 passed to Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::render() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, array given
```

EDIT :

This is how to solve it :

```
public function styleAction()
{
  $response = new Response();
  $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/css');
  // replace this example code with whatever you need
  return $this->render('main.css.twig', [
      'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,
  ],
  $response
  );
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Error message explains everything, isn't it?

Comment: Ok well, I didn't know I could put a Response inside the render method. Thank you anyway.

Comment: If you solved your problem - __write an answer__, don't write updates in a question.